# Export/Import Identity Providers & Clients (12.0.4)

Tags: keycloak

We have multiple environments and it's via human manual input to insert the identity providers and clients when migrating up the environments.

Is there a way to isolate export/import of an identity provider or client? The manual input has brought in errors when migrating identity providers and clients up the environments.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to isolate export/import of an identity provider or
> client?

I have faced the same issue, to solved what I have done was to create a bunch of bash scripts based on the [Rest Admin API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html). For instance:

- Get the clients : `GET /{realm}/clients`
- Create the clients : `POST /{realm}/clients`

First, I call the `get` endpoint, and export its response (*i.e.,* the clients) into a .json that I later use as the payload for the `post` endpoint.

And the same logic applies to the identity providers. It is a bit cumbersome in the beginning to create those scripts, some of them I have already upload to the [my repo](https://github.com/dreamcrash/StackOverflow-/tree/main/Keycloak/RestAdminAPI) (I plan to upload a bunch more of them), but after they are working the process gets smoother.

You can apply the same aforementioned logic, but instead of using bash scripts use the [Keycloak Java API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/7.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/admin/client/Keycloak.html). The other option is to use Keycloak *export Realm* feature; export the realm, extract from the .json file all the content that you do not need, and use the remaining content afterwards with the *import Realm* feature.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't think of this:"export the realm, extract from the .json file all the content that you do not need, and use the remaining content afterwards with the import Realm feature." . Thank you also so much for the scripts on your repo -- I've downloaded them and reviewing both options. Much appreciated.

Comment: @user353829 you are welcome, if you find some bug on them let me know